Change request url using nginx proxy
I am using nginx to reverse proxy my frontend and backend. This is my nginx file:
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    # prevent css, js files sent as text/plain objects
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name app.com
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://frontend.app.com/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }

         location /api {
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_pass https://backend.app.com;
         }

    }
}

When I make an API request with /api, I get a CORS error with backend.app.com as my URL. I want the request to be coming from app.com
I tried playing around with the host configs but the request URL is the same. Both frontend and backend are deployed separately on fly.io
